# Labelling images in docker

Tags: docker

I've got a jenkins server monitoring a git repo and building a docker image on code change. The .git directory is ignored as part of the build, but I want to associate the git commit hash with the image so that I know exactly what version of the code was used to make it and check whether the image is up to date.

The obvious solution is to tag the image with something like "application-name-branch-name:commit-hash", but for many develop branches I only want to keep the last good build, and adding more tags will make cleaning up old builds harder (rather than using the jenkins build number as the image is built, then retagging to :latest and untagging the build number)

The other possibility is labels, but while this looked promising initially, they proved more complicated in practice..

The only way I can see to apply a label directly to an image is in the Dockerfile, which cannot use the build environment variables, so I'd need to use some kind of templating to produce a custom Dockerfile.

The other way to apply a label is to start up a container from the image with some simple command (e.g. bash) and passing in the labels as docker run arguments. The container can then be committed as the new image. This has the unfortunate side effect of making the image's default command whatever was used with the labelling container (so bash in this case) rather than whatever was in the original Dockerfile. For my application I cannot use the actual command, as it will start changing the application state.

None of these seem particularly ideal - has anyone else found a better way of doing this?

Comment: I think I'd probably use a template engine to generate the Dockerfile with the values from the build variables. It seems to me that build time is the correct point to be doing this.

Answer (score 25):

Support for this was added in docker v1.9.0, so updating your docker installation  to that version would fix your problem if that is OK with you.

Usage is described in the pull-request below:

https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/15182

---

As an example, take the following *Dockerfile* file:

```
FROM busybox
ARG GIT_COMMIT=unknown
LABEL git-commit=$GIT_COMMIT
```

and build it into an image named `test` as anyone would do naïvely:

```
docker build -t test .
```

Then inspect the `test` image to check what value ended up for the `git-commit` label:

```
docker inspect -f '{{index .ContainerConfig.Labels "git-commit"}}' test
```

> unkown

Now, build the image again, but this time using the **`--build-arg`** option:

```
docker build -t test --build-arg GIT_COMMIT=0123456789abcdef .
```

Then inspect the `test` image to check what value ended up for the `git-commit` label:

```
docker inspect -f '{{index .ContainerConfig.Labels "git-commit"}}' test
```

> 0123456789abcdef

---

References:

- Docker build command documentation for the [`--build-arg`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#set-build-time-variables-build-arg) option
- Dockerfile reference for the [`ARG`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg) directive
- Dockerfile reference for the [`LABEL`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#label) directive

Comment: This solution doesn't use information from the build process (which occurs inside the container) to create the label, it requires the metadata be known outside of the container.  I believe the OP is in the same situation as me, where we want to expose metadata about the internal build via labels.  For example, I may want to add a label for code-coverage that is determined after a particular RUN command is executed.

Answer (score 3):

You can specify a label on the command line when creating your image. So you would write something like

```
docker build -t myproject --label "myproject.version=githash" .
```

instead of hard-coding the version you can also get it directly from git:

```
docker build -t myproject --label "myproject.version=`git describe`" .
```

To read out the label from your images you can use `docker inspect` with a format string:

```
docker inspect -f '{{index .Config.Labels "myproject.version"}}' myproject
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using docker-compose, you could [add the following to the `build` section](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#labels):

```
labels:
    git-commit-hash: ${COMMIT_HASH}
```

where `COMMIT_HASH` is your [environment variable](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#variable-substitution), which holds commit hash.